# Resize A LVM partion & Create AnotherOne

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, resize, disk-management

I installed Ubuntu on My Laptop By Erasing The Whole Disk & I created It using LVM as it says it is easy to resize the partitions later but now i am unable to resize it.i used gparted in Live Ubuntu Also . 
Please Give Me solution For it

Answer (score 0):

Install `system-config-lvm` for a GUI to help you resize LVM partitions.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm
```

In the Unity dashboard, type `lvm` to start it.

Comment: Useless Tool it doesn't do anything

Comment: @DhireshBudhiraja It's not useless. You need to spend more than 5 minutes with it. Otherwise you'll have to learn some terse command line verbs. In `terminal` type `man system-config-lvm` or `apropos lvm`.